# Plotting a rectangular prism

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm creating a rectangular prism function, whose output looks like this:

[image: rect_prism]

I think that this code can be improved by optimizing the use of `np.meshgrid` with a Python iterator, but I can't wrap my head around it. It might also be possible to do this with fewer plotting calls, but I can't figure that out either. Ideally, I would change the line drawing to use a [Line3DCollection](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Line3DCollection) and the areas to use a [Patch3DCollection](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/api.html#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.art3d.Patch3DCollection) for plotting speed, but I'm still not comfortable enough with the 3D api.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect("equal")

# draw cube
def rect_prism(x_range, y_range, z_range):
    # TODO: refactor this to use an iterator
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)
    ax.plot_wireframe(xx, yy, z_range[0], color="r")
    ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z_range[0], color="r", alpha=0.2)
    ax.plot_wireframe(xx, yy, z_range[1], color="r")
    ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z_range[1], color="r", alpha=0.2)


    yy, zz = np.meshgrid(y_range, z_range)
    ax.plot_wireframe(x_range[0], yy, zz, color="r")
    ax.plot_surface(x_range[0], yy, zz, color="r", alpha=0.2)
    ax.plot_wireframe(x_range[1], yy, zz, color="r")
    ax.plot_surface(x_range[1], yy, zz, color="r", alpha=0.2)

    xx, zz = np.meshgrid(x_range, z_range)
    ax.plot_wireframe(xx, y_range[0], zz, color="r")
    ax.plot_surface(xx, y_range[0], zz, color="r", alpha=0.2)
    ax.plot_wireframe(xx, y_range[1], zz, color="r")
    ax.plot_surface(xx, y_range[1], zz, color="r", alpha=0.2)


rect_prism(np.array([-1, 1]), np.array([-1, 1]), np.array([-0.5, 0.5]))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 7):

Well, unfortunately you can't get any better than this (as far as I have read). And why would you use an iterator in this case ?

I'd however change a bit of the structure of your code, which allows one to easily change the code if there's any need. I didn't changed too many things, just separated the logic into three different functions and added a `for` loop to get rid of some repetition in your code.

As for the plotting calls, you kinda' can't change the number of calls. Those are the perks of plotting things (*in Python at least*).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
ax.set_aspect("equal")


def x_y_edge(x_range, y_range, z_range):
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_range, y_range)

    for value in [0, 1]:
        ax.plot_wireframe(xx, yy, z_range[value], color="r")
        ax.plot_surface(xx, yy, z_range[value], color="r", alpha=0.2)


def y_z_edge(x_range, y_range, z_range):
    yy, zz = np.meshgrid(y_range, z_range)

    for value in [0, 1]:
        ax.plot_wireframe(x_range[value], yy, zz, color="r")
        ax.plot_surface(x_range[value], yy, zz, color="r", alpha=0.2)


def x_z_edge(x_range, y_range, z_range):
    xx, zz = np.meshgrid(x_range, z_range)

    for value in [0, 1]:
        ax.plot_wireframe(xx, y_range[value], zz, color="r")
        ax.plot_surface(xx, y_range[value], zz, color="r", alpha=0.2)


def rect_prism(x_range, y_range, z_range):
    x_y_edge(x_range, y_range, z_range)
    y_z_edge(x_range, y_range, z_range)
    x_z_edge(x_range, y_range, z_range)


def main():
    rect_prism(np.array([-1, 1]),
               np.array([-1, 1]),
               np.array([-0.5, 0.5]))
    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

*NOTE: I've also added `if __name__ == '__main__'`. By doing the main check, you can have that code only execute when you want to run the module as a program and not have it execute when someone just wants to import your module and call your functions themselves.*

Comment: The reason I want iterators is because I figure it would be the first step to putting all the plotting calls into collections. I forgot to put it in the question, but I've edited it now. Not that I expect you to satisfy these new requirements, but just to explain myself.

Comment: This code doesn't work.